# Place a Whatsapp call from my app without saving the number in contacts

Tags: android, call, whatsapp, voip

Place a Whatsapp call from my app without saving the number in contacts.
I cant able to make calls using this code from my app it is saying activity not found exception is coming

Code :

```
Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);

sendIntent.setComponent(new ComponentName("com.whatsapp", "com.whatsapp.Conversation"));
String waNumber = phonestr.replace("+", "").trim();
sendIntent.putExtra("jid", waNumber + "@s.whatsapp.net");
sendIntent.setDataAndType(Uri.parse(""+waNumber),"vnd.android.cursor.item/vnd.com.whatsapp.voip.call");
startActivity(sendIntent);
```

I can able to place call using the contacts of provided number but i dont want to save the number in contacts. Do anyone have the solution for this?